# Formatar valor monetário com AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estou recebendo os seguintes valores

```
<h3 id="valor">Valor Mensalidade: R${{curso_se.preco_curso}}</h3>       
<h1 style="color:green;">PrimeiraMensalidade:R${{curso_se.preco_matricula}}</h1>
```

Mas eles estão vindo com ponto e sem a separação de casas do milhar, por exemplo exemplo: 2.432,00

Tinha tentado dar um *replace* mas não funcionou

```
$("#valor").val(replace(".", ","));
```

Comment: da uma olhada nessa lib chamada [numbro](http://numbrojs.com/getting-started.html) serve pra formar numero, moeda, porcentagem, e ve se te ajuda

Comment: tenta: {{curso_se.preco_curso.replace('.', ',')}}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por favor, não faça esse tipo de gambiarra. Faça do jeito correto.

Adicione o *script* [angular-locale](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n) para a localização que você pretende usar (usei pt-br no exemplo) e depois faça uso do filter [**`currency`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency).

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.preco_matricula = 1150.50 ;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-i18n/1.6.7/angular-locale_pt-br.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <h1>PrimeiraMensalidade: {{ preco_matricula | currency }}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: olá obrigado funcionou e desculpa, achei que esse jeito era o correto me deram essa dica achei que funcionaria. ah obg pelo edit no português também, escrevi correndo.

Comment: Tranquilo, bom poder ajudar.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Fiquei um dia inteiro tentando fazer a gambiarra mencionada anteriormente, e quando resolvi pesquisar corretamente me trouxe até aqui! Valeu!